# Reguarding accessing values of JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to access required values from my json response in order to load into a drop down box. But I get `undefined` as drop down items.

**Here is my json response:**

```
{"currency":[{"code":"USD","dateModified":"2015-10-30T20:43:58","decimalPlace":"2","id":1,"status":true,"symbolLeft":"$","symbolRight":"","tiendayaOrderses":[],"title":"US Dollar","value":1.00000000},{"code":"EUR","dateModified":"2015-10-30T20:43:58","decimalPlace":"2","id":2,"status":true,"symbolLeft":"","symbolRight":"€","tiendayaOrderses":[],"title":"Euro","value":0.76775432},{"code":"GBP","dateModified":"2015-10-30T20:43:58","decimalPlace":"2","id":3,"status":true,"symbolLeft":"£","symbolRight":"","tiendayaOrderses":[],"title":"Pound Sterling","value":0.64524455}]}
```

**Here is how I fetch my response :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "currencies",
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function() {
            alert('error');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(data.currency, function(index) {
                $.each(data.currency[index], function(key, value) {
                    //curncyDrop is the drop-down box
                    $('#curncyDrop').append('<li><a>' + value.title +
                        '</a></li>');


                });

            });
        }

    });
});
```

This loads all the data to the drop-down instead of loading required(*title*) value:

```
$('#curncyDrop').append('<li><a>' + value + '</a></li>');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the nested `each` statements for? It looks like you only have one array in the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = {
  "currency": [{
    "code": "USD",
    "dateModified": "2015-10-30T20:43:58",
    "decimalPlace": "2",
    "id": 1,
    "status": true,
    "symbolLeft": "$",
    "symbolRight": "",
    "tiendayaOrderses": [],
    "title": "US Dollar",
    "value": 1.00000000
  }, {
    "code": "EUR",
    "dateModified": "2015-10-30T20:43:58",
    "decimalPlace": "2",
    "id": 2,
    "status": true,
    "symbolLeft": "",
    "symbolRight": "€",
    "tiendayaOrderses": [],
    "title": "Euro",
    "value": 0.76775432
  }, {
    "code": "GBP",
    "dateModified": "2015-10-30T20:43:58",
    "decimalPlace": "2",
    "id": 3,
    "status": true,
    "symbolLeft": "£",
    "symbolRight": "",
    "tiendayaOrderses": [],
    "title": "Pound Sterling",
    "value": 0.64524455
  }]
}



$.each(data, function(index, value){
$.each(value, function(indx, val){
$('#curncyDrop').append('<li><a>' + val.title + '</a></li>');
  $('#curncyDrop').append('<li><a>' + val.value + '</a></li>');
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='curncyDrop'></ul>
```

Try like this

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an unnecessary loop going on there, as long as your data is valid JSON and the title property exists you should be able to do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "currencies",
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.currency, function (key, value) {
                $('#curncyDrop').append('<li><a>' + value.title +'</a></li>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

If it's not a JSON object then use JSON.parse( data ), if you're still getting an undefined error I'd recommend console.log( data ) to help investigate further.

Comment: tried without nested `each`.  getting same result but with only 3 `undefined`. :)

Comment: @MadushanPerera console.log out data and value to check what's being passed through.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var currencyData = data.currency;
    $.each(currencyData, function(key, value){
       //curncyDrop is the drop-down box
       $('#curncyDrop').append('<li><a>' + value.title +'</a></li>');
    });
```

Comment: there is no need to parse since he specified the dataType to json